# subgroup having index $2$ of $R^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The question is to find all the subgroups of $R^*$ (non-zero reals under multiplication) of index $2$.

The index can be found out for finite groups. How to find subgroups having certain index for an infinte group?

The index is also the no. of distinct cosets(left/right). Is it the way to proceed to the answer? Please put light into it.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$**Hint**

If $H$ is such a subgroup, then the quotient group $\R^{\star}/H$ is a group of order $2$, hence the squares of all of its element are the unit element $H$ of $\R^{\star}/H$.

Comment: so, if any element x (non identity) belongs to $R^*$/H , then its order will be 2. so |rH| = 2 $\Rightarrow$ $r^2$H=H$\Rightarrow$ |r|=2$\Rightarrow$r= +1 or -1.. So H can be $R^*$ or $R^+$. Is it right?? please check. thanks.

Comment: Not quite. $r^{2} H = H$ iff $r^{2} \in H$. So $H$ contains all squares. Now the set $S = (\mathbb{R}^{\star})^{2}$ of squares is a subgroup of index $2$, because $\mathbb{R}^{\star} = S \cup (-1)S$. So $H = S$.

Comment: ohh yes.. that's the exact answer. I made a mistake of not considering the basic coset property of $r^{2} H = H$ if an only if $r^{2} \in H$.

Comment: But this "set of all squares" is a specific subset, with a *much* nicer description...

Comment: Of course ;-) $\ $

Answer (score 0):

You can construct homomorphisms (surjective) from $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the only group of order two and compute the kernel.

Answer (score -1):

negative$\times$negative$=$...?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/572358)

Comment: @MickG Well, it does. Answer the question I ask, and you find the unique subgroup of index two.